# Always starting LC colpitts oscillator

Tags: oscillator, passive-networks, resonance, oscillation

Is there a way to make an LC oscillator that works in most circumstances?
Which is able to start up an keeps oscillating for a wide range of inductors?

I'm asking this because I made a LC oscillator which can switch between several capacitor values (with analog switches) for operation in different frequency ranges.

In the [simulation (falstad)](http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+5e-9+45.7144713268909+25+5+50%0Al+272+288+272+208+2+0.000143+0.02244833862372821%0AT+368+208+432+288+2+0.001+1+0.022399311730157922+-0.032508253712653035+0.999%0Ar+368+208+272+208+0+5%0At+560+368+608+368+0+1+0.6848260324213309+0.7301009530677653+100%0Ac+560+368+560+416+2+2.2e-7+0.7301009530677653%0Ac+480+368+480+416+2+2.2000000000000002e-8+-1.026242513952398%0As+400+352+400+400+0+1+false%0As+336+352+336+400+0+1+false%0Ar+336+400+336+432+0+1%0Ar+400+400+400+432+0+1%0Aw+480+288+432+288+0%0Aw+432+208+560+208+0%0Aw+560+208+560+368+0%0Aw+480+368+480+352+0%0Aw+480+352+480+288+0%0Ar+608+352+608+288+0+100%0AR+608+288+608+192+0+0+40+12+0+0+0.5%0Ag+480+416+480+480+0%0Ag+560+416+560+480+0%0Ag+608+448+608+480+0%0Ac+400+432+400+448+2+2.2000000000000002e-8+1.3171708382061276%0Ac+336+432+336+448+2+4.7000000000000004e-8+0.3100928262671274%0Ag+400+448+400+480+0%0Ag+336+448+336+480+0%0Aw+336+352+400+352+0%0Aw+400+352+480+352+0%0Al+272+288+368+288+0+2.9000000000000003e-7+-0.022448338623728192%0Ac+432+208+432+288+0+3.5e-11+1.7563434670201634%0Ac+368+208+368+288+0+3.5e-11+1.7289515827203463%0Aw+608+448+608+384+0%0Ac+608+352+688+352+0+0.000001+0.34367417076663215%0Ar+688+352+688+448+0+100000%0Ag+688+448+688+480+0%0Ar+480+352+608+352+0+1000%0Ax+235+172+415+175+4+24+External%5Csinductor%0Ax+271+336+444+339+4+24+Analog%5Csswitches%0Ab+289+172+236+304+0%0Ab+272+336+459+432+0%0Ao+15+32+0+20738+20+0.1+0+2+15+3%0Ao+31+32+0+4107+20+0.0001953125+1+2+31+3%0Ao+16+32+7+20739+20+0.05+2+1+2.5%0Ao+0+32+0+4099+5+0.05+3+2+0+3%0A38+0+0+0.000049999999999999996+0.00015+Inductance%0A) is working for every possible capacitor combination. But in reality it is only working when both capacitors are enabled.

I don't need a perfect sine wave, but I do need a frequency dependent on the external inductor and adjustable in frequency range.

So I'm looking for an oscillator that starts in most conditions and is able to keep its oscillation going.
Might this be possible by over-sizing the amplifier gain or using other components like opamp's. The frequency will be used to measure the inductance of the external inductor. Or any tips on how to dimension all the parts to make it more stable?

**Update:**

- The transformer is used to provide galvanic isolation from the external inductor which will be placed in the pavement as a vehicle detector

[image]

Comment: *Is there a way to make an LC oscillator that works in most circumstances?* Sure, an oscillator only oscillates if it has sufficient **loopgain**. To learn about loopgain read: http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Oscillators/osc11.php and  https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/oscillators.html

Comment: *"I'm looking for an oscillator that starts in most conditions and is able to keep its oscillation going."* To me that is what the definition of an oscillator is. Can you try and explain what you are searching for or what your question really is. Also, why do you use a transformer to connect your inductor AND, quite importantly, can you show a schematic that doesn't look like it suffers from the black death or smallpox?

Comment: @Andyaka this should be better

Comment: In the document as referenced by Bimpelrekkie thetre is an error: "Therefore the closed loop gain must be 1 (unity)" This is wrong. Theoretically, the closed-loop gain is infinite. Rather, it is the loop gain (open-loop conditions) which must be unity in accordance with the oscillation criterion.

Comment: Bruce....while changing the value of the feedback capacitor in the feedback network you not only changes the frequency (that fulfills the oscillation condition) but also the damping factor of the feedback circuit (that means: The loop gain). Hence, the amplitude condition for oscillation is not met anymore. Hence, the gain of the active block must be modified at the same time. In general, it is not easy to find an oscillator that allows frequency tuning with one element only.

Comment: @LvW "...it is not easy to find an oscillator that allows frequency tuning with one element only.." That is why I'll be happy with a distorted sine wave because of a too high gain so I have some margin for other configurations and still have a feedback gain >=1.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you for the two interesting articles. I understand the conditions needed for the oscillator to start. But I have a hard time determine the feedback gain. What I don't understand is that when both switches are enabled the oscillator works in this case there is the least amount of feedback because of the capacitor voltage divider. And when I make the feedback higher by opening one of the switches the oscillation stops.

Comment: How realistic is your transformer model? Over what range of frequencies do you wish oscillation?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf The desired frequencies are between 20kHz and 180kHz depending on the external inductor 50µF - 1500µF and if the frequency makes a jump of 20kHz by adding or removing a capacitor.Transformer used is 78601/3c